# Delegate callback for UICollectionReusableView subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, header, uicollectionreusableview

I have a custom header/footer class

```
class CustomCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
   var pageControl: UIPageControl!
   ...
}
```

and use it in `UICollectionViewDataSource` appropriate method:

```
func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
        at indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == customKind {
        ...//return CustomCollectionReusableView object
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is if I have multiple sections with the same this header/footer then how should I get callback to know in which of them user clicked on `pageControl` (get indexPath)?

If it was `UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell` subclass I could just call a custom delegate in it with a cell-sender param and then call for example `collectionView.indexPath(for:)`.

The problem is there is no such method for headers/footers. There is `collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElements(ofKind:)` only which returns multiple `indexPath` objects.

How to resolve this issue correctly? Should I set callback block or indexPath inside this view?

Comment: Since it's a custom one, can't you have an "id" on your CustomCollectionReusableView?

Comment: When you want to identify a view you can use the tag property.

Comment: It is inconvenient to use default identifiers like `cellIdentifier` because they are often used for other purposes and "reusable identifier" may be single for multiple cells or headers/footers. `tag` property - possibly but I can't for example save position in it as is because other views may have tags 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: @Gargo - Abstract questions are very difficult to answer. What are you trying to do? Are you adding interactive section headers, and you want to inform the controller when the user does something? Best to provide complete **minimal** code showing what you need to solve.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I "add interactive section headers and want to inform the controller about it". But not only about event by itself - I have multiple headers and I want to know which one caused this event. And I can post a code sample for similar situation with cells but it has no sense for headers because one of the essential methods doesn't exist

Comment: @Gargo - as with one of your other questions, it is ***much*** easier to offer help if you provide more detail - preferably with a **complete minimal** example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use protocol/delegate pattern, but Swift likes **closures**.

Depending on what all you need to do, you may want to take different approaches.

***IF*** you know your collection view data structure will not change, you can capture the `section` in a closure.

For example:

```
class InteractiveHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    public var myValueChanged: ((Int) -> ())?

    @objc func pgChanged(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        myValueChanged?(sender.currentPage)
    }

    // all the rest of your header (supplementary) view setup

}
```

Then, your `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` might look something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: InteractiveHeaderView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! InteractiveHeaderView
        
        let thisSection: Int = indexPath.section
        
        // set properties in headerView

        // set the closure
        headerView.myValueChanged = { [weak self] val in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            // do something based on the val passed by the section's header view
            self.updateValueForSection(section: thisSection, val: val)
        }
        
        return headerView
        
    default:
        assert(false, "Invalid element type")
    }
    
}
```

On the other hand, suppose you have 30 sections, and based on user-interaction or data events, you might be deleting / inserting / re-ordering sections, you don't want to rely on the captured `section`.

In that case, we can pass back the header view instance, and loop through the visible supplementary views to find the index path.

So our `closure` changes to:

```
class InteractiveHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

    public var myValueChanged: ((UICollectionReusableView, Int) -> ())?

    @objc func pgChanged(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        myValueChanged?(self, sender.currentPage)
    }

    // all the rest of your header (supplementary) view setup

}
```

and we can do this when setting the closure:

```
headerView.myValueChanged = { [weak self] thisView, val in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    // user interacted with a section header view, so
    //  the header view executing this closure must be visible...

    // get the indexPaths of the visible supplementary views
    let idxPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElements(ofKind: kind)

    for pth in idxPaths {
        if let thisHeaderView = self.collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: kind, at: pth), thisHeaderView == thisView {
            // do something based on the val passed by the section's header view
            self.updateValueForSection(section: pth.section, val: val)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a complete example..

We'll start by defining a "section" data struct:

```
struct MySection {
    var myVal: Int = 0
    var numItems: Int = 0
}
```

Where `myVal` will be an index into an array of colors, which we'll use for the background of the label in a collection view cell, and `numItems` will be the number of items in the section.

It will look like this when running:

[image]

Changing the current page in the section header will change the background color of the labels in that section:

[image]

---

**`SimpleCell: UICollectionViewCell` class** - with a single, centered label...

```
class SimpleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "simpleCell"
    
    public var bkgColor: UIColor = .systemRed { didSet { theLabel.backgroundColor = bkgColor } }
    
    public var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
        label.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        theLabel.backgroundColor = bkgColor
        
        // so we can see the cell framing
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
    }
}
```

---

**`InteractiveHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView` class** - with a label and a page control...

```
class InteractiveHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    static let identifier: String = "interactiveHeaderView"
    
    public var myValueChanged: ((UICollectionReusableView, Int) -> ())?
    
    public var title: String = "" { didSet { titleLabel.text = title } }
    public var numPages: Int = 1 { didSet { pageControl.numberOfPages = numPages } }
    public var curPage: Int = 0 { didSet { pageControl.currentPage = curPage } }
    
    private let titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    private let pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        [titleLabel, pageControl].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            pageControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            pageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        titleLabel.textColor = .white
        
        pageControl.backgroundStyle = .prominent
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numPages
        
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pgChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
    }
    
    @objc func pgChanged(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        myValueChanged?(self, sender.currentPage)
    }
    
}
```

---

**`InteractiveHeaderViewController: UIViewController` class** - to demonstrate...

```
class InteractiveHeaderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var myData: [MySection] = []
    
    let sectionColors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
        .systemBrown, .systemCyan
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // some sample data
        let iCounts: [Int] = [
            7, 16, 9, 5, 8, 12, 13, 10, 3, 7, 11
        ]
        iCounts.forEach { n in
            // we'll start the data with all sections using color Zero
            let s = MySection(myVal: 0, numItems: n)
            myData.append(s)
        }
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 4.0
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4.0
        fl.itemSize = .init(width: 54.0, height: 36.0)
        fl.sectionInset = .init(top: 4.0, left: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 4.0)
        fl.headerReferenceSize = .init(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.identifier)
        collectionView.register(InteractiveHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: InteractiveHeaderView.identifier)
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    
    func updateValueForSection(section: Int, val: Int) {
        
        myData[section].myVal = val
        
        for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
            if let c = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: section)) as? SimpleCell {
                c.bkgColor = sectionColors[myData[section].myVal]
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension InteractiveHeaderViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData[section].numItems
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimpleCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
        cell.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath.section),\(indexPath.item)"
        cell.bkgColor = sectionColors[myData[indexPath.section].myVal]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: InteractiveHeaderView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! InteractiveHeaderView
            
            let thisSection: Int = indexPath.section
            headerView.title = "Sec: \(thisSection)"
            headerView.numPages = sectionColors.count
            headerView.curPage = myData[thisSection].myVal
            
            headerView.myValueChanged = { [weak self] thisView, val in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                // user interacted with a section header view, so
                //  the header view executing this closure must be visible...
                
                // get the indexPaths of the visible supplementary views
                let idxPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElements(ofKind: kind)
                
                for pth in idxPaths {
                    if let thisHeaderView = self.collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: kind, at: pth), thisHeaderView == thisView {
                        // do something based on the val passed by the section's header view
                        self.updateValueForSection(section: pth.section, val: val)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return headerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```